# Supervised clustering/classification in a streaming environment

Tags: classification, clustering, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I am faced with a challenging problem and I was wondering whether someone could point me in the right direction of existing research literature.

The problem is the following: **Given a stream of data points, cluster them into equivalent clusters with no knowledge of what the clusters are.**

This resembles the online clustering problem, where data points need to be clustered together. However, clustering is an unsupervised algorithm and the data points are usually clustered based on a distance measure between pairs of them.

In my case, the data points are not simple text documents, although a part of their features is sparse. Instead they contain very important individual features and more feature engineering could be done to improve the representation. As I believe that the problem of assigning these data points to clusters is rather challenging I have doubts that an unsupervised distance metric would be able to do well enough, especially since good performance is vital.

The idea I have is to replace the distance metric in an online clustering algorithm with a classification or a regression model. The model would predict whether the two data points belong to the same cluster. A clustering algorithm might perform better if a continuous number was output which can be interpreted as a distance.

My question are:

1. Is this an established approach and if so could you point me to research literature? I do not know where to start looking.
2. If not, does the approach sound reasonable or am I overlooking something?
3. If yes, do you have any suggestions on how to formulate the model?

Thanks a lot for your help.

**Updated description:** To describe the problem differently, you can think of the underlying problem as a process that creates a stream of distinct hidden states. Each data point that we observe is a noisy description of one such hidden state. A data point can be thought of as a *report* of a hidden state occurring, which means that it will happen at some point after the hidden state occurs with decreasing probability over time (and never before the hidden state happens). Each hidden state may have many descriptions in the form of data points associated with it or just one (potentially zero as well, but not much we can do about those). The goal is to identify the true hidden states by associating data points to them, with as high reliability as possible. The data points are described with a number of features, and importantly, they have a time associated with them (as do the hidden states).

Two further complexities can arise: (1) although difficult to formalize, there is a notion of similarity between hidden states and some will be more difficult to distinguish from one another than others, and (2) a further goal is to infer true properties of the hidden state from the noisy descriptions of the data points (instead of just relying on a group of data points to provide a sufficient description).

**Update 2**: The hidden states may or may not be dependent on each other. In a simplified view, we can assume that the states are generated independently of each other and there are no transitions between states. A system can be in a number of them at any point. Thinking about it, states is probably not the right terminology, but I do not know what is.

Comment: All you want, and more: [A tutorial on Bayesian nonparametric models](http://web.mit.edu/sjgershm/www/GershmanBlei12.pdf)

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent clusters"? Is this referring to the size of the clusters, the stability of established clusters (decision boundaries), or something else?

Comment: @JasonSanchez By equivalent clusters I mean that the data points in a single cluster are all descriptions of the same true state.

Comment: @Emre I edited the above post to offer a more generative story of the problem.

Comment: @Matt could you give more of a flavour about what the data look like, and what types of decisions you hope to make off the back of them?

Comment: Sure @conjectures. The data are real world events and the data points are based on textual reports of those events characterized by a set of features (including top X sparse words, but much more as well). Inferring the actual events that happened is a goal in itself, although a lot can be done with it afterwards.

Comment: About once an hour, a new person submits a 500 word autobiography. There are many correct ways to group these people using the text and other submitted information. Perhaps we try to group people based on education, job status, hobbies, race, gender identity, or even favorite sport. Maybe we complete a purely unsupervised method and find natural clusters in the data. Each one of these would likely result in different clusters. If we don't let the algorithm know which specific "states" we are looking for, there is no reason to think it will return results consistent with your expectations.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Because there are many correct ways to group the same data, it seems impossible to expect any algorithm to predict an observation belongs to a specific class (or "state") without ever seeing an example of that particular state.

Comment: @JasonSanchez That is likely correct. In the original post, I mentioned that supervised data of previous observations being grouped together could be obtained. The states are not different from each other in that they would group according to different criteria - they use the same features to determine whether something belongs together. In your example, that would mean that we always wish to group together people with, for example, the same hometown.

Comment: I will attempt to define the general problem more clearly. You are trying to assign an observation to a specific category or class, which is a classification problem. You have labeled training data and unlabeled data you would like to predict (potentially in an online matter). Although most of the unlabeled data is expected to contain classes that are the same general type as was seen in the training data, there are new classes that were not present in the training data. So, the training data might be labeled with hometowns, but the data to predict has different hometowns. Correct?